# Determine VCS for incoming HTTP Request

Tags: git, http, go

I have a custom import domain, that is routed to the correct place when the `go get` command is executed as defined by this meta tag: `<meta name="go-import" content="{{.BaseURL}}{{.RouterKey}} git {{.RouterValue}}">`. I am trying to test out the new module stuff in [go1.11rc1](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/golang-nuts/UmbvkJmdEP0/xvwo9ukKDgAJ). It specifies [here](https://research.swtch.com/vgo-module#Publishing) that this `meta` tag needs to change from the vcs of `git` to `mod`.

Is there anyway to determine which vcs is being used (git or mod) for an incoming request so I can then serve the right html as we test out new modules in Go1.11?

Comment: The article is about vgo, not the release candidate. Are you sure it applies? I've had no problems downloading modules without changing any meta tags.

Comment: When I run a `go1.11rc1 get ...` it says unknown revision for a package inside another repo. The repo has a tag that I can run `go1.11rc1 get` for but for the package in a sub-folder in the repo, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother. Just use same old format as always. It's still supported, and 'mod' was only for vgo.

See the official (albeit DRAFT) [Go 1.11 Release Notes](https://tip.golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Remote_import_paths) for details:

> The meta tag has the form:
>
> ```
> <meta name="go-import" content="import-prefix vcs repo-root">
> ```
>
> *snip*
>
> The vcs is one of "bzr", "fossil", "git", "hg", "svn".